# Trying to find a quote by Pema Chodron

Tags: reference-request, zen

I'm looking for a quote by Pema Chodron. In my memory, she's having a discussion with a Zen master, and the quote goes something like this;

Pema: "what do you do when things fall apart?"

Zen Master: "I stay"

I seem to remember it being in her book When Things Fall Apart, but I searched it for the word 'stay' and I couldn't find this anywhere.

Does anybody recognise where it comes from? Maybe it's from a video or an audio recording of an interview with her? Maybe it exists only in the recesses of my memory?

Comment: Perhaps this reference may help: https://www.brainpickings.org/2017/07/17/when-things-fall-apart-pema-chodron/

Comment: Hi I searched 'stay' in that page but I couldn't find it, does it have the quote I'm looking for or is it just talking about related ideas? I'm hoping to find that exact quote if it exists

Comment: I reckon your brain has mixed it up in some form. stay sounds like sit, anyway

Comment: @again_insane_buddhist, yes it's actually 'I agree', see my answer. In hindsight, 'Zen' may have been a more distinctive keyword to search than 'stay'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the quote I was looking for last year,

> I once asked the Zen master Kobun Chino Roshi how he related with fear, and he said, "I agree. I agree."

It is on page 9 of my copy, which is a 2005 edition printed on the Element imprint of HarperCollins.

Answer (score 0):

> “To be fully alive, fully human, and completely awake is to be
> continually thrown out of the nest. To live fully is to be always in
> no-man's-land, to experience each moment as completely new and fresh.
> To live is to be willing to die over and over again. ”

― Pema Chödrön, When Things Fall Apart: Heart Advice for Difficult Times

Comment: This is a nice quote, but it's not the one I was looking for. I was looking for one where Pema is talking to a Zen master. I actually found it a while back, I might post it a an answer later if I remember